# Fetch 'top stories' by facebook api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

It seems now Facebook API does not get the 'top stories' even the setting of my Facebook account is top stories. Indeed, it shows the 'recent stories'; so I want to ask is there anyway I can get the top stories (in the same order we see in our news feed) instead of recent stories by graph api or FQL?

Thanks,

Moti